# Combining Fields in Oracle SQL Select Statement - Date Plus Varchar2

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Using Oracle / SQL

I am trying to combine a DATE field with a VARCHAR2(4) field that acts as 24 Hour Time in a SELECT statement. I also need to present the results and sort by DATE desc... I need the sort order to also take the time into consideration....

datefield (date) DD-MON-YY
timefield (varchar2) example 1535 or 0432

Do I keep this as a Date field or Varchar2 Field and how do I accomplish this ??

This is what I have so far

```
select 
to_date(to_char(datefield, 'DD-MON-YY') || ' ' || timefield, 'DD_MON_YY HH24MI') as date_selected
order by 
to_date(to_char(datefield, 'DD-MON-YY') || ' ' || timefield, 'DD_MON_YY HH24MI') desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use an order by clause something like:

> order by trunc(datefield) desc, timefield desc

trunc() discards any time element in the DATE column (which is actually a DATETIME value in Oracle), then a second order sort on timefield.

Answer (score 0):

try using [to_timestamp()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions193.htm) instead of to_date ()

`select to_timestamp(to_char(datefield, 'DD-MON-YY') || ' ' || 'timefield', 'DD_MON_YY HH24MI') as date_selected order by to_timestamp(to_char(datefield, 'DD-MON-YY') || ' ' || 'timefield', 'DD_MON_YY HH24MI') desc;`

Comment: and why should he prefer to_timestamp to to_date?

Comment: @miracle173 sorry totally forgot about your question heres a link https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Working_with_Dates_and_Times_in_PostgreSQL why I in general use to_timestamp() maybe its not necessary for this special question but it offers a much better support for special operations, hes trying to invent the "wheel again" where we already have a very good implementation. especially with calenders where things can get complicated, its in my opinion better to leave that stuff to professionals

Answer (score 0):

Code you posted is invalid (misses the FROM clause).

As DATEFIELD column's data type is DATE, you need to convert it to a string (using TO_CHAR and desired format mask). Then, concatenate that string with yet another string (which is a TIMEFIELD column). Finally, sort can be done by both those columns as they are.

Here's an example:

```
SQL> create table test
  2  (
  3     datefield   date,
  4     timefield   varchar2 (4)
  5  );

Table created.

SQL> insert into test
  2       values (sysdate, '1850');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test
  2       values (sysdate + 8, '0812');

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL>   select to_char (datefield, 'dd-mon-yy') || ' ' || timefield date_selected
  2      from test
  3  order by datefield desc, timefield desc;

DATE_SELECTED
--------------
10-feb-18 0812
02-feb-18 1850

SQL>
```